# pandas_datareader.data not returning all stock values from start to end date

Tags: python, pandas, datareader, yahoo-finance, stocks

I am trying to get stock data from yahoo using `pandas_datareader.data` and i keep getting missing sections of data. here is what i have coded. all i want to do right now is return all the data for the dates between the start and end dates

```
import pandas as pd 

import pandas_datareader.data as web

from datetime import datetime



ibm = web.DataReader('IBM',  'yahoo', datetime(2015,1,1)

datetime(2016,1,1))
```

and right now this is returning this:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogITk.png)

I am confused why i am getting the ellipse with all the missing data when i try to create my set. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the ellipse is not just in the visual output?

Comment: That looks like a display issue, if you look at `ibm.info()` and `ibm.tail()` you should see that the shape and final rows are present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `pandas` displays the result [(as explained here)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#overview). `pandas` omits rows that exceed the `pd.set_option('max_rows', X)` setting (`default` is 50 I believe). You can see the limit using `pd.options.display.max_rows`.

Try `ibm.info()` and you should see that there are more rows than displayed.

Your query results in:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 252 entries, 2015-01-02 to 2015-12-31
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Open         252 non-null float64
High         252 non-null float64
Low          252 non-null float64
Close        252 non-null float64
Volume       252 non-null int64
Adj Close    252 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 13.8 KB
None
```

But displays as (not `rows x columns` info at the bottom despite elipsis):

```
                  Open        High         Low       Close    Volume  \
Date                                                                   
2015-01-02  161.309998  163.309998  161.000000  162.059998   5525500   
2015-01-05  161.270004  161.270004  159.190002  159.509995   4880400   
2015-01-06  159.669998  159.960007  155.169998  156.070007   6146700   
2015-01-07  157.199997  157.199997  154.029999  155.050003   4701800   
2015-01-08  156.240005  159.039993  155.550003  158.419998   4236800   
2015-01-09  158.419998  160.339996  157.250000  159.110001   4484800   
2015-01-12  159.000000  159.250000  155.759995  156.440002   4182800   
2015-01-13  157.259995  159.970001  155.679993  156.809998   4377500   
2015-01-14  154.860001  156.490005  153.740005  155.800003   4690300   
2015-01-15  156.690002  156.970001  154.160004  154.570007   4248400   
2015-01-16  153.820007  157.630005  153.820007  157.139999   5756000   
2015-01-20  156.699997  157.330002  154.029999  156.949997   8392800   
2015-01-21  153.029999  154.500000  151.070007  152.089996  11897100   
2015-01-22  151.940002  155.720001  151.759995  155.389999   6120100   
2015-01-23  155.029999  157.600006  154.889999  155.869995   4834800   
2015-01-26  158.259995  159.460007  155.770004  156.360001   7888100   
2015-01-27  154.940002  155.089996  152.589996  153.669998   5659600   
2015-01-28  154.000000  154.529999  151.550003  151.550003   4495900   
2015-01-29  151.380005  155.580002  149.520004  155.479996   8320800   
2015-01-30  153.910004  155.240005  153.039993  153.309998   6563600   
2015-02-02  154.000000  154.660004  151.509995  154.660004   4712200   
2015-02-03  154.750000  158.600006  154.750000  158.470001   5539400   
2015-02-04  157.210007  158.710007  156.699997  156.960007   3678500   
2015-02-05  157.289993  158.589996  157.149994  157.910004   5253600   
2015-02-06  157.339996  158.080002  156.229996  156.720001   3225000   
2015-02-09  156.000000  157.500000  155.399994  155.750000   3057700   
2015-02-10  156.740005  158.559998  155.080002  158.559998   4440600   
2015-02-11  157.759995  159.089996  157.169998  158.199997   3626700   
2015-02-12  158.720001  159.500000  158.089996  158.520004   3333100   
2015-02-13  158.779999  160.800003  158.639999  160.399994   3706900   
...                ...         ...         ...         ...       ...   
2015-11-18  134.789993  135.910004  134.259995  135.820007   4149200   
2015-11-19  136.210007  137.740005  136.009995  136.740005   4753600   
2015-11-20  137.369995  138.919998  137.250000  138.500000   5176400   
2015-11-23  138.529999  138.869995  137.119995  138.460007   5137900   
2015-11-24  137.649994  139.339996  137.309998  138.600006   3407700   
2015-11-25  138.369995  138.429993  137.380005  138.000000   3238200   
2015-11-27  138.000000  138.809998  137.210007  138.460007   1415800   
2015-11-30  138.610001  139.899994  138.520004  139.419998   4545600   
2015-12-01  139.580002  141.399994  139.580002  141.279999   4195100   
2015-12-02  140.929993  141.210007  139.500000  139.699997   3725400   
2015-12-03  140.100006  140.729996  138.190002  138.919998   5909600   
2015-12-04  138.089996  141.020004  137.990005  140.429993   4571600   
2015-12-07  140.160004  140.410004  138.809998  139.550003   3279400   
2015-12-08  138.279999  139.059998  137.529999  138.050003   3905200   
2015-12-09  137.380005  139.839996  136.229996  136.610001   4615000   
2015-12-10  137.029999  137.850006  135.720001  136.779999   4222300   
2015-12-11  135.229996  135.440002  133.910004  134.570007   5333800   
2015-12-14  135.309998  136.139999  134.020004  135.929993   5143800   
2015-12-15  137.399994  138.970001  137.279999  137.789993   4207900   
2015-12-16  139.119995  139.649994  137.789993  139.289993   4345500   
2015-12-17  139.350006  139.500000  136.309998  136.750000   4089500   
2015-12-18  136.410004  136.960007  134.270004  134.899994  10026100   
2015-12-21  135.830002  135.830002  134.020004  135.500000   5617500   
2015-12-22  135.880005  138.190002  135.649994  137.929993   4263800   
2015-12-23  138.300003  139.309998  138.110001  138.539993   5164900   
2015-12-24  138.429993  138.880005  138.110001  138.250000   1495200   
2015-12-28  137.740005  138.039993  136.539993  137.610001   3143400   
2015-12-29  138.250000  140.059998  138.199997  139.779999   3943700   
2015-12-30  139.580002  140.440002  139.220001  139.339996   2989400   
2015-12-31  139.070007  139.100006  137.570007  137.619995   3462100   

             Adj Close  
Date                    
2015-01-02  153.863588  
2015-01-05  151.442555  
2015-01-06  148.176550  
2015-01-07  147.208134  
2015-01-08  150.407687  
2015-01-09  151.062791  
2015-01-12  148.527832  
2015-01-13  148.879114  
2015-01-14  147.920202  
2015-01-15  146.752415  
2015-01-16  149.192426  
2015-01-20  149.012033  
2015-01-21  144.397834  
2015-01-22  147.530934  
2015-01-23  147.986654  
2015-01-26  148.451876  
2015-01-27  145.897925  
2015-01-28  143.885151  
2015-01-29  147.616379  
2015-01-30  145.556132  
2015-02-02  146.837859  
2015-02-03  150.455161  
2015-02-04  149.021536  
2015-02-05  149.923486  
2015-02-06  149.837432  
2015-02-09  148.910029  
2015-02-10  151.596622  
2015-02-11  151.252431  
2015-02-12  151.558385  
2015-02-13  153.355812  
...                ...  
2015-11-18  133.161622  
2015-11-19  134.063613  
2015-11-20  135.789160  
2015-11-23  135.749949  
2015-11-24  135.887208  
2015-11-25  135.298946  
2015-11-27  135.749949  
2015-11-30  136.691151  
2015-12-01  138.514746  
2015-12-02  136.965669  
2015-12-03  136.200937  
2015-12-04  137.681377  
2015-12-07  136.818611  
2015-12-08  135.347970  
2015-12-09  133.936153  
2015-12-10  134.102824  
2015-12-11  131.936088  
2015-12-14  133.269455  
2015-12-15  135.093050  
2015-12-16  136.563691  
2015-12-17  134.073412  
2015-12-18  132.259616  
2015-12-21  132.847878  
2015-12-22  135.230309  
2015-12-23  135.828370  
2015-12-24  135.544053  
2015-12-28  134.916580  
2015-12-29  137.044105  
2015-12-30  136.612715  
2015-12-31  134.926379  

[252 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! so is there a way to change what you can see and not get the row of ellipse? or at least to access it?

Comment: This is really just a display setting issue, the data are avaiable to you. If you want to view on screen, adjust your display max_row setting accordingly (see links). You can always save to csv or excel.

Comment: Did this answer your question or do you need any additional info?